# Como imprimir todos os índice de uma lista em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Como faço para printar os índices de uma lista? Quero que a saída fique assim:

```
Indice: 0  1  2  ...
likes:  0  0  0 ...
```

Um post é representado como um elemento de uma lista. O índice da lista indica o número de post. Por exemplo, o primeiro post (postagem número 1) corresponde ao índice zero (0) da lista.

Eu consegui isto:

```
Indice: 1
likes:  0
```

Mas não consegui por completo. Abaixo está o código:

```
postagem = []

print('1) Criar um post')
alternativa = int(input())
t = postagem.append(0)

if(alternativa == 1):

    if(len(postagem) < 1):
        postagem.append(0)
        print('Indice:', postagem.index(0))
        print('likes:', postagem[0])

    if(len(postagem) >= 1):
        postagem.append(0)
        print('Indice:', len(postagem) - 1)
        print('likes', postagem[1])
```

Comment: Explique o por que do índíce `2` não aparecer em `Indice: 0  1  3...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é:

```
postagens = [1, 0, 5, 9]

print('Índice:', *range(len(postagens)))
print('Likes: ', *postagens)
```

O asterisco serve para fazer o [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), ou seja, ao fazer `print(*lista)` é como se você fizesse `print(lista[0], lista[1], etc...)`. E como o `print`, por padrão, imprime um espaço entre os argumentos, você já obtém a saída desejada:

```
Índice: 0 1 2 3
Likes:  1 0 5 9
```

Outra forma é usando [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
postagens = [1, 0, 5, 9]
separador = ' '
print('Índice:', separador.join(map(str, range(len(postagens)))))
print('Likes: ', separador.join(map(str, postagens)))
```

Tive que usar [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) para transformar os números em strings, já que o `join` dá erro se os elementos não forem strings. A saída é a mesma.

Se a lista for vazia, o programa mesmo assim imprime "Índice:" e "Likes:" (e não imprime nada depois, pois não há elementos na lista). Se quiser incluir uma verificação para só imprimir algo se a lista tiver elementos:

```
if postagens: # se a lista não for vazia
    separador = ' '
    print('Índice:', separador.join(map(str, range(len(postagens)))))
    print('Likes: ', separador.join(map(str, postagens)))
```

`if postagens` verifica se a lista não é vazia, já que [listas vazias são consideradas `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Repare também que mudei o nome da lista para `postagens`, pois se ela vai ter várias postagens, é melhor que o nome esteja no plural para indicar o que de fato tem ali. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad) (se bem que neste caso, o nome poderia ser `quantidades_likes` ou apenas `likes`, pois é o que de fato tem ali - não tem uma postagem propriamente dita, mas enfim).

A diferença para a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443632/112052) é que lá é incluído um espaço a mais no final da string, que dependendo do caso, pode ou não fazer diferença (para este caso específico, parece não fazer, mas pensando de forma mais geral, a saída do programa pode ser passada para outro, que espera que não haja esse espaço a mais, por exemplo - mesmo que não faça diferença para um exercício simples, acostume-se a pensar nesses detalhes, pois [há casos em que um espaço extra no final faz diferença sim](https://ideone.com/ONHQV8)).

---

Só um detalhe, se os valores forem maiores que 10, os dados ficarão desalinhados. Por exemplo, se a lista for `[10, 2, 4335, 10000]`, a saída será:

```
Índice: 0 1 2 3
Likes:  10 2 4335 10000
```

Neste caso, você pode usar as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) para alinhar os itens. Por exemplo, você pode escolher um tamanho arbitrário (digamos, 7) e alinhar as colunas para que ocupem este tamanho:

```
def formatar(valor):
    return f'{valor:>7}' # alinhar à direita, usando 7 posições

postagens = [10, 2, 4335, 10000]
if postagens:
    print('Índice:', ''.join(map(formatar, range(len(postagens)))))
    print('Likes: ', ''.join(map(formatar, postagens)))
```

O formato `>7` diz para alinhar à direita, ocupando 7 posições (e as posições não usadas à esquerda são completadas com espaços). O resultado é:

```
Índice:       0      1      2      3
Likes:       10      2   4335  10000
```

---

Claro que se tiver um número com mais de 7 dígitos, haverá desalinhamento do mesmo jeito (e para valores pequenos, parece haver um "desperdício" de espaço). Neste caso, uma solução mais geral seria, para cada valor, obter a quantidade de espaços que ele ocupa, e usar esta quantidade para alinhar:

```
def formatar(valor, tamanho):
    return f'{valor:>{tamanho}}'

postagens = [10, 2, 4335, 10000, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1111, 4]
if postagens:
    indices = []
    likes = []
    for i, p in enumerate(postagens):
        tamanho = max(len(str(i)), len(str(p))) + 2
        indices.append(formatar(i, tamanho))
        likes.append(formatar(p, tamanho))

    print('Índice:', ''.join(indices))
    print('Likes: ', ''.join(likes))
```

Usei [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para percorrer a lista e ao mesmo tempo obter o respectivo índice de cada elemento.

Para o tamanho, usei [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) para pegar o maior tamanho entre o índice e o valor (pois o índice pode ser 10 e o valor 1, por exemplo, e nesse caso eu precisaria usar 2 espaços para alinhar, por isso preciso saber qual dos dois tem o maior tamanho). Somei 2 para ter dois espaços a mais separando os valores (se quiser mais espaço separando os elementos, basta somar ao tamanho).

A saída é:

```
Índice:    0  1     2      3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13    14  15
Likes:    10  2  4335  10000  1  2  3  4  5  6   1   2   3   0  1111   4
```

---

Outro ponto é que esse trecho do seu código não faz muito sentido:

```
if(len(postagem) < 1):
    postagem.append(0)
    print('Indice:', postagem.index(0))
    print('likes:', postagem[0])
```

Quer dizer, se a lista for vazia, você insere um elemento nela, depois procura o índice dele com `index` (mas como só tem um elemento, você sabe que é zero) e também imprime o primeiro elemento (que você inseriu 2 linhas antes, então vc já sabe que é zero). Nesse caso, você poderia simplesmente escrever o zero diretamente:

```
if postagens: # lista não está vazia
    ... imprime, escolhendo um dos métodos acima
else: # lista vazia
    print('Indice: 0')
    print('likes: 0')
```

Repare também que no Python - diferente de algumas outras linguagens - não precisa dos parênteses para a condição do `if`.

Answer (score 3):

Para imprimir todas as postagens, basta percorrer todos os elementos com um laço `for`, sendo que você deve utilizar um range para imprimir os índices.

Para deixar todas as postagens em uma única linha, defina uma string com espaço (`" "`) como argumento para o parâmetro `end` da função `print`, para que a função não faça quebra de linha.

Veja abaixo o código:

```
postagem = [3, 1, 7]

print("Índice:", end = " ")

for indice in range(len(postagem)):
    print(indice, end = " ")

print("\nLikes: ", end = " ")

for post in postagem:
    print(post, end = " ")
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/LinedHealthyEnvironment

---

Duas outras formas até mais simples que eu confesso ter esquecido e que está na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443648/157404), é utilizando *unpacking* e o método [`join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) de string. Na forma de *unpacking*, você utiliza um asterisco (`*`) para passar cada elemento da lista como argumento para a função.

Logo cada elemento será impresso na mesma linha.

```
postagens = [3, 1, 7]

print('Índice:', *range(len(postagem)))
print('Likes: ', *postagem)
```

A outra forma é utilizando o método `join` que serve para juntar todos os elementos de um iterável dentro de uma string.

O problema é que este método não separa o elementos, então precisamos utilizar uma função chamada [`map()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/) para aplicar a formatação.

```
def formatar(elemento):
    return str(elemento) + " "

postagem = [3, 1, 7]

print("Índice:", "".join(map(formatar, range(len(postagem)))))
print("Likes: ", "".join(map(formatar, postagem)))
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/AblePureMinimalsystem

Uma coisa bastante interessante dessa forma acima para imprimir as postagens, é que você pode formatar cada postagem alterando apenas o retorno da função `formatar`. Veja abaixo:

```
def formatar(elemento):
    return "| <" + str(elemento) + "> "
```