# como retorna os indices de uma lista python

Tags: python, lista

Tenho a lista:

`lista  = [0,0,0,0]`

Como posso retornar os índices dessa lista para que fique dessa forma:

```
Índice: 0 1 2 3
item:   0 0 0 0
```

```
def f1():
    #funcão criar um post, cria um novo post com 0 likes 
    post.append(0)
    print(print(),'O post nro.',len(post),' tem sido criado.')    
    print('A lista de postagens é a seguinte:\nÍndice: 0\nLikes: 0')
    input('Aperte Enter para para voltar')
```

**Objetivo**

'printar'

O post nro. 3 tem sido criado.

A lista de postagens é a seguinte:

```
Índice: 0 1 2 3
Likes: 0 0 0 0
```

Aperte R para voltar

Comment: range(0, len(lista)) ?

Comment: vai listar a quantidade mas eu precisava mostrar todos os indices

Comment: Dá uma olhada sobre a função ```enumerate```: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como imprimir todos os índice de uma lista em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443628/como-imprimir-todos-os-%c3%adndice-de-uma-lista-em-python)

Answer (score 3):

Não há um método para recuperar os índices de uma lista, por que esses
índices sempre são número sequenciais, começando no zero.

não tem "índices diferentes".

Se você precisar dos índices avulsos, pode usar o builtin `range`:
ele também vai te dar uma sequuência de números, começando no zero
por padrão.

Mas, se quiser mostrar na tela os índices, por exemplo, em um laço for - 
o  natural em Python é usar o builtin `enumerate`. Ele pode ser usado
em um `for` e vai te retornar o índice, junto com o elemento naquele indice:

`for indice, elemento in enumerate(lista): ...`

Só que se você realmente quiser postar os índices em uma linha de cima, e os elementos numa linha de baixo, a coisa complica: você não tem como naturalmente ficar passando entre a linha de cima e a debaixo em Python (nem nenhuma outra linguagem, se a saída for no terminal): voce essencialmente teria que criar uma tabela em memória, gerar a saída de cada célula da tabela e imprimir essa tabela. nesse exemplo simples, é mais fácil fazer um for com `range` para imprimir os números, e outro for com os elementos da lista, para imprimir 
os elementos em si.

O mais natural é simplesmente imprimir na vertical:

```py
print("indicet - elemento")
for indice, elemento in enumerate(lista):
    print (f"{indice:<10}{elemento}")
```

(Aqui usei uma regra de formatação para impressão que
diz para alinhar o índice a esquerda, com 10 espaços, com o uso do `:<10` dentro da chave)

para fazer na horizontal, como você quer, basta fazer:

```
...
print(f"Índices: {list(range(len(lista))}")
print(f"Likes  : {lista}")
```

Comment: obrigado jsbueno conseguir entender agora e consegui fazer na horizontal

Answer (score 1):

> Se o objetivo do seu código é de apenas resolver um exercício ou matar
>   a curiosidade sobre um determinado tipo de exibição essa solução não é
>   mais indicada para você, pois mesmo o código parecendo simples ele faz
>   uso de um recurso sofisticado que é o [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). Seria o mesmo
>   que matar uma barata com um escopeta.

Caso seu código seja parte algo maior e esse conjunto de dados vá posteriormente ser modificado, operacionalizado, analisado, recalculado e reexibido você pode dispor da possibilidade de usar um [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) e método [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) para tabular os seus dados.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

l = [2, 4, 6, 3, 8]

#Cria um DataFrame sobre um dicionário índice/valor sobre a lista l com um cabeçalho # 
#de índices e uma única linha, de nome likes e do tipo inteiro, contendo os valores correspondentes
df = DataFrame(dict(enumerate(l)), index=["likes:"], dtype=int)

#Ajusta o nome do eixo das colunas 
df = df.rename_axis("índice:", axis="columns")

print(df)
```

Saída:

```
índice:  0  1  2  3  4
likes:   2  4  6  3  8
```

Código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/ElectronicEuphoricFrontpage

Answer (score 0):

Opa, amigo!
vamos lá:
se vc quer printar os índices de uma lista nomeada como lista,
vc pode fazer o seguinte:

```
lista = [0,0,0,0]
lista_indices = []
for i in lista:
   lista_indices.append(lista.index(i))
print(lista_indices)
```

espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: obrigado allen só que esta retornando [0,0,0,0] ou seja retorna os items da lista nao o indice

Comment: voce tem que atribuir os índices a uma outra lista e chamar ela no lugar

Answer (score 0):

Usa o a função `enumerate`:

**Input**

```
lista = [0,0,0,0]

print(f"Índices:", end=" ")

for chave, _ in enumerate(lista):
    print(chave, end=" ")

print("\n")

print(f"Valores:", end=" ")

for _, valor in enumerate(lista):
    print(valor, end=" ")
```

**Output**

```
Índices: 0 1 2 3 

Valores: 0 0 0 0
```